# How to open pop up with tool bar

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i need to open a page with same window.

i used code like

```
window.open('NZFReferenceSelector.aspx?RefId= ' + refID, '_self', parameters, false);
```

the page is open with in same page.

but it does not show the tool bar?

iam using vs 2010 and javascript
need help
Thanks ,

pooja

Answer (score 3):

try following for the tool bar

```
window.open("http://www.javascript-coder.com", "mywindow","status=1,toolbar=1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `_self` frame target name (document will be loaded in the same frame). Use `_blank` to create unnamed window or specify window name.

```
window.open('NZFReferenceSelector.aspx?RefId= ' + refID, '_blank', parameters, false);
```

Or

```
var winName = "TestWin"; 
var popUp = window.open('NZFReferenceSelector.aspx?RefId= ' + refID,winName, parameters, false);

if(popUp==null || typeof(popUp)=='undefined') 
{
 alert('Please disable pop-up blocker');
}
```